# Вывод определенного количетва данных в таблицу angular js

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день.
Имеется страница на которую выгружаются данные json

```
   <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-Total' ">
<td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{ $index + 1}}</td>
<td><img src="{{cup.Addon_1}}" width="60" height="60"></td>
<td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.user}}</td>
<td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.Total}}</td>
```

Как можно сделать что-бы выводилось только допустим 5 строк?

Comment: [фильтр limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно